# use format name as function input in proc fcmp

Tags: sas

I have two different formats defined.

```
proc format;
value fmtA
1 = 3
2 = 5
;
value fmtB
1 = 2
2 = 4
;
run;
```

function `myfun` returns formatted value

```
proc fcmp outlib=WORK.pac.funcs;
    function myfun(n);
        val = put(n,fmta.);
        return (val);
    endsub;
run;
```

I want to make this a bit more dynamic - val will be based on function input.

**EDIT**

```
proc fcmp outlib=WORK.pac.funcs;
    function myfun(n,myfmt $);
        if myfmt = 'fmtA' then val = put(n,fmtA.);
        else if myfmt = 'fmtB' then val = put(n,fmtB.);
        else val = n;
        return (val);
    endsub;
run;

data test;
    n = 2;
    myfmt = 'fmtA';
    output;
    myfmt = 'fmtB';
    output;
    myfmt = 'fmtC';
    output;
run;

data test2;
  set test;
    /* try to do sth like this */
    value = myfun(n,myfmt);
run;
```

This solution works. However it requires a long list of checking when I have so many different formats. And it's not possible before I take a look at format name in the input `test` dataset.

Comment: add a second parameter to the function add a case statement within the function to get the required format based on the parameter passed

Comment: instead of using as format get a string resembling the format type and check whether the string matches any format and then use the format. for example fmtA and fmtB are strings that can be passed. these strings are compared with the strings in the case statement if its fmtA then add the put function with the fmtA. format as statement for the case.

Comment: @SivaprasathV The format passed to function is actually based on existing dataset column values.  I don't know all the format names, but I just need to pass a column value (which supposed to be a format) to that function.

Comment: can you state the condition for the formatting of the values? what condition should n should pass to get format fmtA. or fmtB. ?

Comment: @SivaprasathV I have edited the question. Not sure if the solution is the one you mentioned. Or I misunderstood your point?

Comment: If you want something like putn and putc aiming at the data type you can use something like this http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/69762/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p12zqzvwx4dv6kn1p9crijxswolk.htm

Comment: PUTN/PUTC allow the second parameter to be a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the PUTN() function.

```
proc format;
value fmtA 1 = '3' 2 = '5' ;
value fmtB 1 = '2' 2 = '4' ;
value fmtc 1 = '1' 2 = '3' ;
run;
data test;
  do myfmt = 'fmtA.','fmtB.','fmtC.';
  do n= 1,2;
    str = putn(n,myfmt);
    value = input(str,32.);
    output;
  end;
  end;
run;
```